# Excel formula to Sum 12 rows every 3 rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to make a sum of 12 rows every 3 rows in excel. That is, I need to sum first from C4 to C15, then from C7 to C18, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `OFFSET` function for this, also volatile, but shorter!

Assuming first formula in `E2` copied down

`=SUM(OFFSET(C$4,(ROWS(E$2:E2)-1)*3,0,12))`

I prefer this because it explicitly contains all the required information

C4 = first cell to sum,
E2 = first cell with formula,
3 = row increment,
12 = number of cells to sum

The above gives you the  sums on successive rows from `E2` (or any other chosen cell) down. If you actually want the sum to be shown **every 3 cells** e.g. on the first row for each sum then that's simpler - try this formula in `D4` copied down

`=IF(MOD(ROWS(E$2:E2),3)=1,SUM(C4:C15),"")`

.......or even easier.....just put this formula in `D4`

`=SUM(C4:C15)`

....leave `D5` and `D6` blank, then select the range `D4:D6` and drag down

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the non-volatile INDEX function

```
=SUM(INDEX(C:C,ROWS($1:1)*3+1):INDEX(C:C,ROWS($1:1)*3+12))
```

This works because INDEX returns a reference so you can use the normal Ref1:Ref2 notation for a range.

Answer (score 1):

`=SUM(INDIRECT("C"&ROW(1:1)*3+1&":C"&ROW(1:1)*3+12))`

Be warned that `INDIRECT()` is a volatile formula... This means that any change made anywhere in the workbook this formula will recalculate and can cause performance issues.

Comment: @Eva You are very welcome, if this is the answer that you used, please mark the answer as accepted by using the tick to the left... Thank you.